# How to add UI Objects (Image) to a UITextView or UITextField?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextview

I would like to achieve something like the following for a `UITextField` or a `UITextView`.
The Object added to will be treated like a string when we delete texts.

I know I can add a backgrand image and get it done with too many codes.

Please let me know the best possible way to achieve this and kindly give me some pointers.

[image]

Comment: it is MFMailComposeViewController...

Comment: Its facebook Dialog. But that is not I wanted. I wanted to know the bode in the TextField. Please let if me know.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use Text Kit.  Using a UITextView with Text Kit allows you to define exclusion paths (which could be used to form text around subviews) or to add attachments into the text directly.

Here's another answer that gives some pretty good direction: [How to wrap text around attachments using iOS7 Text Kit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18968820/how-to-wrap-text-around-attachments-using-ios7-text-kit)